# Profile of a platinum-iridium meter bar

Tags: measurements, units, history, metrology, length

The former meter standard, [platinum-iridium meter bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#International_prototype_metre_bar), had a specific cross section somewhat resembling mixed variant of letters "X" and "H" with serifs ([Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Platinum-Iridium_meter_bar.jpg)):

[image]

What was the reasoning behind using this particular structural shape? Why not just an ordinary I- or T-shaped beam, or a cylinder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That modified X profile is called the Tresca section, named after the French scientist [Henri Tresca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Tresca) who proposed it. The cross section is designed to provide maximum rigidity in a bar of fairly small dimensions and mass, and to minimize the effects of any slight bending that may take place when a bar is in normal use.

In the image, the lower surface of the central rib coincides with the bar's *neutral plane*, where change in length with flexure is minimum. The two lines that define the metre are engraved on the neutral plane. Flexure is to be expected, because during a measurement the metre bar is supported only at its two [Bessel points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_points#Bessel_points) (at 1/4 and 3/4 of its length) instead of lying on a flat table.

[image]